# Functional core lib functions ordering and return types

Tags: rust, types, functional-programming

I have a question with regards to functional rust, and how the core lib functions work. It seems they return different things, depending on their ordering.

As an example, I have made a simple function that doubles numbers, and takes only even numbers. So, a map and a filter is needed. It looks like this:

[image: working_as_intended]

However when I change the order of the map/filter, the return of filter changes, like so:

[image]

I understand the error, and that I need to dereference the variable, but I don't know why this change happens. Can someone explain to me what is going on here?

Comment: Please do not post text as images. Also, post the full error message from `cargo check`, not your IDE.

Comment: I said that for your future posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`slice::iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter) returns a [`std::slice::Iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html). That structure implements [`Iterator<Item = &T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html#impl-Iterator), so it yields references.

[`Iterator::filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter) returns a [`std::iter::Filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Filter.html), which implements `Iterator<Item = I::Item>`, aka it yields whatever the iterator *it transforms* yields. So in the second snippet, since `iter()` yields `&i32`, `iter().filter(..)` yields `&i32`.

In the first snippet however there's a [`Iterator::map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) between the two. *That* yields whatever the mapping function returns, which in your case is an `i32`. Therefore the filter which follows matches that, and yields an `i32` as well.

The last pieces of the puzzle are that:

- since it doesn't take ownership `filter`'s callback receives a *reference* to the input value, *even if that value is already a reference*, so if it's transforming an `Iterator<Item=&T>` it receives an `&&T`
- while the `.` operator will dereference as many times as necessary, other operators *will not dereference at all*
- because references are so common in Rust, rather than implement only [`i32 % i32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Rem.html#impl-Rem%3Ci32%3E) the stdlib also implements:

  - [`&i32 % i32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Rem.html#impl-Rem%3Ci32%3E-1)
  - [`i32 % &i32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Rem.html#impl-Rem%3C%26%27_%20i32%3E)
  - [`&i32 % &i32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Rem.html#impl-Rem%3C%26%27_%20i32%3E-1)

  However that's where the stdlib stops, there is no `impl Rem<i32> for &&i32`. Therefore no `&&i32 % i32`, therefore your second version can not find a trait implementation to call.

FWIW while you can of course dereference in the filter callback, there's an iterator adapter to avoid working with references to simple types (as, as you've discovered, that's often less convenient; it's also commonly less efficient): [`Iterator::copied`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied) will transform an `Iterator<Item=&T>` into `Iterator<Item=T>` as long as `T` is [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) (meaning trivially copiable and usually fairly small, like an integer).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to use .iter().copied for primitives from now on!
And good to know ´.´ will auto-dereference - I guess that's what's happening when passing in references to functions as well?

Comment: "I guess that's what's happening when passing in references to functions as well?" no, it does happen when calling *methods* (the subject will get dereferenced until the method is found), but for arguments to function they are what they are, if you need to reference or dereference you have to do it yourself.

Comment: @Masklinn Not always, [deref coercions do take place](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4353fc1424247180a2b213bb6fec3a7f).